# Missing management UI for Azure Service Bus namespace

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm missing the management UI in the Azure Portal for several Azure Service Bus namespaces. I can't see any Entities, Settings, Monitoring, etc. These are very old namespaces that were previously created in the old management UI. The queues created under the namespaces are working perfectly - I just can't see them to manage them. I don't think they were created with ACS, but it's possible they were. I can't easily re-create them without coordinating the re-issuing of public keys with many vendors. Is there a way I can re-attach the Azure Portal to these Service Bus namespaces?

[image: Here's what I see]

[image: Here's what I expect to see]

Comment: I would try to ping Azure support first. Not something I've seen myself happening.

Comment: Saw the same thing just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started seeing this myself a week or two ago. Just F5 and it should load as usual. I assumed it's a portal bug, although it could be a weird browser/extension interaction.

Comment: I didn't expect it to, but this worked. I see this problem across multiple browsers/operating systems, so I think you're right to call it a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected to face problems with the namespaces which are ACS authorized. As you mentioned that the namespaces were created in Old Management Portal, there is possibility that they might be created with ACS authorization. Here is the [blog post by Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2018/05/18/acs-migration-guide/), which explains the deprecation of ACS in near future and steps to migrate the namespaces from ACS to SAS authorization. Hope this solves your problem.